# dantzig-wolfe decomposition

Tags: dantzig-wolfe-decomposition

Hi I have been reading about Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition from Bazaraa (Linear Programming and Network Flow).

The master problem shown below. Why is it that $(w, \alpha) = c_B B^{-1}$  where $w$, and $\alpha$ are the dual variables for equation 7.1 and 7.2 respectively?

[image: Master problem for Dantzig-Wolfe Decomposition]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $c_BB^{-1}$ represents the primal objective value and by strong duality theorem, if the solution is optimal then primal objective value must be equal to dual objective value.